# on click event firing but ajax not happening

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am loading data rows using ajax, now i am trying to delete row by clicking delete image icon in that row( delete image is `<input type='image'` loading with row data).

now by clicking on delete row icon it is  firing but ajax not running to delete data in MySql Db.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document.body).on('click', '.deleterow', function(){
   var userid = $(this).val();    
   var examid = $("#examid").val();    
   //alert(userid);
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"deletecandidateexam.php",
        data:"candid="+userid+"examid="+examid,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
            if(data = "norecord"){
                alert("No Recodrs Found to Delete Selected Candisate..");
            }if(data = "success"){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();                    
            }if(data = "failure"){
                alert("Failed to Delete Selected Candisate, Please Try Later..");                   
            }       
        }
    });    
 });      
});
```

Comment: `data:"candid="+userid+"examid="+examid` should be `data:"candid="+userid+"&examid="+examid`? Note the `&`.

Comment: Is it not firing or is it firing and php gives you an error? Try deletecandidateexam.php directly in your browser with  given values and then you will know.

Comment: Does your code execute the the callback success?

Comment: Thanks @ KIKO Software

Comment: ajax running and my PHP code also executing deleting data in DB, but am not getting call back data in to success function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to prevent the default action of the button otherwise your form will get submitted:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.deleterow', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    .... rest of code
});
```

And fix the data error:

```
data: 'candid=' + userid + '&examid=' + examid
```

Comment: True in most cases, but <input type='image'> doesn't have a default submit action?

Comment: if it's in a form it will usually submit that form when clicked

Comment: @pete  Thank you, ajax running and my PHP code also executing deleting  data in DB, but am not getting call back data in to success function.

Comment: are you echoing "norecord", etc in your deletecandidateexam.php?  if you `console.log(data)` in your success function, what does it say? also you may want to change the `if`s after the first one to `else if`s

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($checkval) == 0){
           $nrc = "norecord";
         echo json_encode($nrc);
         exit();
    }

Comment: if($result){
    $sces = "success";
    echo json_encode($sces);
}else{
    
    $flr = "failure";
  echo json_encode($flr);
}

Comment: ok in your js success function add `console.log(data)` and see what is returned by pressing `f12` and selecting the console tab (if in chrome or ff)